# Search and replace in VIM with special charecter

Tags: vim

How do I change this string:

```
<web-app>/v1/avai
```

to this:

```
http://foo.domain.com/v1/avai
```

in Vim?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I tried the following :%s/"\<web-app>\>"/"http\://foo.domain.com\:8080"/g

Comment: Add it to your question, with proper formatting.

Answer (score 1):

The only part you have to escape are the slashes in your URL.

So `:s/<web-app>/http:\/\/foo.domain.com/` should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks @Tshaero it worked. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

If it is just one line:

```
1 - copy the url to the clipboard
2 - type:

ct/  .................. change until but no include /
Ctrl-r + .............. paste the clipboard content
```

If there are a bunch of them scattered all over the file:

```
:%s/^<web-app>/\=@+
```

NOTE: The clipboard register '+' must contain your url